# Get the coordinates by the click on the map Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, bing-maps

How to implement it? Map is Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map.

Comment: What about if you start by the reference guide? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: I read. The solution is not found.

Comment: have you reviewed Map samples? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/site/search?query=map&f[0].Value=map&f[0].Type=SearchText&ac=4

Answer (score 4):

try and use this to get location on tap on map ....

```
private void Map_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
     GeoCoordinate asd = this.Map.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate(e.GetPosition(this.Map));
}
```

i hope it will help ...

Answer (score 0):

First  add the following reference **Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.dll** and implement `.xaml` as follows

```
xmlns:maps="clr-amespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps"
```