# Ask user to point a location in map Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want the user to select a point of his choice on a map and get the GeoCoordinate of that point. How can I achieve this?

I am currently able to launching a map.
Is there something similar to the photoChooser Task which I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487627/get-the-coordinates-by-the-click-on-the-map-windows-phone-8)

```
private void Map_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
 {
    GeoCoordinate asd = this.Map.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate(e.GetPosition(this.Map));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am testing your solution. Will report soon.